# libndi_newtek missing from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to compile ffmpeg on macOS to add libndi_newtek dependency but I am getting the following message,

```
Unknown option "--enable-libndi_newtek".
See ./configure --help for available options.
```

libndi_newtek is missing from help section. Has ffmpeg removed this dependency?

Answer (score 7):

`libndi` support was removed from FFmpeg. This was a response to NewTek violating the license by distributing nonfree binaries.

Some [background here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7589) and [here](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/11263/).

Comment: So, can we still use NDI as input to FFmpeg or not?

Comment: No, it cannot be used, since support was removed.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* an **ffmpeg-ndi** package.

I don't know for what platforms this is applicable, but the Arch Linux repository has a package with NDI re-enabled. As of this writing, it was updated less than 2 months ago. For Linux other than Arch, the source can probably be downloaded and built.

- **Link**: [ffmpeg-ndi](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ffmpeg-ndi/)
- **Description**: Complete solution to record, convert and stream audio and video with NDI restored and enabled
- **License**: custom: nonfree and unredistributable